# Backbone.js won't post to the specified URL

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone.js application running with this generator https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone. I need to make a `POST` request to a service running on a different server and domain. On my model I have the following:

```
urlRoot: 'https://custom.com/',

saveData: function(params) {
  this.set(params);
  if(this.isValid()) {
    this.save(null, {
      url: 'api/v1/data',
      success: function(model, response, options) {
        // success
      },
      error: function(model, response, options) {
        // error
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When I try posting the data, it posts the data to `http://localhost:9000/api/v1/data`. Any idea why Backbone chooses to `POST` to the server it is runnning on, instead of the settings I supplied (`https://custom.com/api/v1/data`)?

On my server, I'm running Restify on top of NodeJS (I'm allowing origin from any client for testing purposes). Here's how I setup CORS:

```
// Setup CORS
api.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
  return next();
});
```

I doubt there is a problem with the server, since it isn't even being reached by the client because somehow the specified URL automatically maps to `http://localhost:9000/api/v1/data` instead of `https://custom.com/api/v1/data`.

UPDATE: If i do it "manually" with jQuery (without using Backbone's API), it works:

```
saveData: function() {
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     data: this.toJSON(),
     url: 'https://custom.com/api/v1/data'
  })
  .success(function() {
    // success
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // fail
  });
}
```

Is there anyway to do it using Backbone's API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a `url` as an option to `Backbone.Model.prototype.save` will circumvent the url generation logic (i.e. `urlRoot`) and assume the url option is the full path (including the domain if not POSTing to the current domain).

You should instead set the `urlRoot` to the path of the entity (or whatever your backend platform may call it), so in your case it should be:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'https://custom.com/api/v1/data'
});
var myModel = new MyModel();
myModel.save(); // POST https://custom.com/api/v1/data
// Assuming that returns an id of '123';
myModel.save(); // PUT https://custom.com/api/v1/data/123
myModel.destroy(); // DELETE https://custom.com/api/v1/data/123
```

If your server isn't set up to handle Backbone style RESTful endpoints then you probably just want to override `Backbone.Model.prototype.url` instead of `urlRoot`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only wanna test calls to the server, you can download a chrome extension. It will allow you to make calls to a different domain. Here : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Answer (score 0):

Post request to a different domain will not work from browser. Better way to handle this is you can set some redirect rules in server.

Comment: How would you do so in Apache?

Comment: ProxyPass /api/v1 https://custom.com/api/v1
ProxyPassReverse /api/v1 https://custom.com/api/v1

Comment: yuo have to put this type of rules in vhost files

Comment: It's possible to make ajax requests to different domains by setting up the CORS headers correctly on the serving domain. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: A server receiving should be CORS-enabled  with your domain. if you dont have access to that then it is not possible